# DataTrigger Binding to a ToggleButton within another namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml

I try to access a ToggleButton that is within a separate UserControl to Trigger a DockPanel.Style DataTrigger.

Here is how I made it work when both, the ToggleButton and the DockPanel, are in the same namespace:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="OneToggleButton"
          Content="Click me..." />

<DockPanel>
  <DockPanel.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" 
              Value="Visible"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                     ElementName=DetailsBookToggleButton}" 
                     Value="False">
          <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" 
                  Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Style>

  <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="..." />

</DockPanel>
```

But now when I move the ToggleButton into an other file (other namespace) it doesn't work anymore. ElementName (as I understand it) only works for elements within the same file. 
So how can I manage a Binding to the IsChecked of my ToggleButton in another file?

Anybody have a suggestion? Would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, the term you are looking for is "name scope", and there is no way to reference an element defined in another name scope.  Arguably, you *should not* be allowed to do this.

Rather than binding one UI element to another, consider binding them both to a common property, either in your view model, on some common ancestor element, or via dependency property inheritance.